# SQLite JDBC - How to populate new Database

Tags: java, database, sqlite, jdbc

I was given two databases, and am supposed to create a table in a new database that stores information about the given databases.
So far I created a table in a new database. I also defined its attributes, but I am stuck on how to populate this table.

The attributes are things like 'original_db, 'original_field' etc , but I don't know how to access this information? Especially since I would need to connect jdbc to 3 databases (the new one, and the 2 old ones) at the same time. Is ths even possible?

I am new to working on databases and SQLite, so sorry if this is a stupid problem.
I would be so grateful for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

What I can grasp from your question is you don't know how to insert data into it?

You could do this in your schema.sql when creating the db e.g the schema would look something like.

```
DROP TABLE users;
CREATE TABLE users(id integer primary key, username varchar(30), password varchar(30), email varchar(50), receive_email blob, gender varchar(6));

DROP TABLE lists;
CREATE TABLE lists(id integer primary key, user_id integer, list_id integer, name varchar(50), creation_date datetime, importance integer, completed blob);

DROP TABLE list_item;
CREATE TABLE list_item(id integer primary key, list_id integer, name varchar(50), creation_date datetime, completed blob);
```

then you could make a data.sql file or something with

```
INESRT into users VALUES(NULL, "name", ...);
```

and then do in the terminal

```
sqlite3 database.db <- data.sql
```

or you could start a sqlite interactive session in the same working directory as your db and manually type in the code

e.g type in

```
sqlite3 databasename.db
```

and then type in commands from there

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I already managed to create the table, but my main problem is how to work on multiple databases at the same time? 
Like, i have this table that I want to fill with data from another table, without manually typing in the values. So how can i address one db when i am trying to fill another?

Let's say I want to copy the value of one field of the given db into the new db. How could I do this with a query?